# Linking a join table with another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my rails app, I have three tables: `forms`,`languages` and `levels`.

My `forms` table holds info about curricula people submit.
It has various columns regarding the submitter personal info, and one of them is their foreign language knowledge level.

My `languages` table holds the languages that should be present in the curriculum form, and it has the `id`,`name`,`created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

My `levels` table holds the language knowledge levels, right now it has only Basic, Medium and Advanced, and it has the `id`,`name`,`created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

I was able to relate my `languages` table and my `levels` table using the following code:

```
#app/models/level.rb
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :languages
end

#app/models/language.rb
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :levels
end
```

Now, a fourth table exists in my database to relate these two tables, the `languages_levels` table, which has nothing else but the `language_id` and the `level_id` columns.

Is there a way, using [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), to relate this `languages_levels` table to my `forms` table in a way that for every language recorded in the `languages` table, a set of radio button inputs present in the `levels` table to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you described, using the bridge table (using the `language_lavels` table with `has_and_belongs_to_many`) seems to be a wrong approach. You just need three-way one-to-many relations.

In other words, you should create a model, say `LanguageLevel`, which belongs to `Form`, `Language`, and `Level`. Then you can populate `LanguageLevel` for each `Language` for each `Form`.

Comment: After spending 3 hours not knowing what to do, I tried your approach and it seems like the only way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check this screencasts they might point you in the right direction:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

http://railscasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2

Comment: Didn't help me too much because I am trying to make a three-way join, and those only help with normal two table joins.